# Counting amount of copied files in C#

Tags: c#

I have a computer list that I am copying files to.

I am attempting to create a label that shows which computer is being copied to at the time. For ex: "Copying to computer1... (x of 10)", where 10 is based on the amount of lines in a string array:

```
var lineCount = File.ReadLines(complist).Count();
```

How do I get the first number (x) to change every time a new file is copied? (1 of 10), (2 of 10), etc...

Here is what my label looks like:

```
label2.Text = ("Copying to " + @computer + "... ( of " + lineCount + ")");
```

EDIT: Here is my copy operation. The files are copied to each remote system.

```
        string complist = openFileDialog2.FileName;
        string patch = textBox2.Text;
        string fileName = patch;
        string patchfile = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
        var lineCount = File.ReadLines(complist).Count();

        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(complist))
        {
            //Checks if C:\PatchUpdates exists on remote machine. If not, a folder is created.
            if (!Directory.Exists(@"\\" + line + @"\C$\PatchUpdates"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"\\" + line + @"\C$\PatchUpdates");
            }

            //XCOPY patch to every computer
            System.Diagnostics.Process processCopy = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
            StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/c xcopy " + patch + " " + @"\\{0}\C$\PatchUpdates /K /Y", line);
            processCopy.StartInfo = StartInfo;
            processCopy.Start();
            label2.Text = ("Copying to " + @line + "... (" + @num + " of " + @lineCount + ")");
            processCopy.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you loop through the files and do the copying?

Comment: set a counter, increase inside the starting of loop

Comment: Edited to show the copying of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare `num` as a variable and increment it in the loop:

```
int num = 0;

foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(complist))
{
    num++;

    //...
    label2.Text = ("Copying to " + line + "... (" + num + " of " + lineCount + ")"); 
    //..
}
```

By the way, your are reading the lines in the file twice. Once you get the number of lines and another time to get the lines themselves.

Using `ReadLines` is better if you have a large file and you don't want to read all the lines at once (for memory concerns). However, if the file is relatively small, then you can instead just read the file lines once by using `ReadAllLines` and store them in a variable like this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(complist);

var lineCount = lines.Length;

int num = 0;

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    num++;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I took the advice on the foreach loop as I was reading the computer list twice. Didn't even realize I was doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep an index that you increase every time you go to the next line.

```
int num = 0;
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(complist))
{
  ++num;
  string progress = string.Format("Copying to {0} ({1} of {2})", line, num, lineCount);
  // ...
```

I kept your variable names though I strongly suggest something better than `line` and `num` (like `computerName` and `computerIndex`).

Alternatively, you can replace the `foreach` by an old-fashioned `for` loop, which basically inverts the whole thing:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(complist);
for (int num = 0; num < lineCount; ++num)
{
  string line = lines[num];
  string progress = string.Format("Copying to {0} ({1} of {2})", line, num, lineCount);
  // ...
```

Comment: I'm definitely going to change the variable names. When reading the code again I was only confusing myself. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < lineCount; i ++)
{
    label2.Text = string.Format(@"Copying to {0} ({1} of {2})", complist[i], i + 1, lineCount;
    // Copy logic ... 
}
```